# Pandas Converting date string (only month and year) to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime object to datetime. In the original dataframe the data type is a string and the dataset has shape = (28000000, 26). Importantly, the format of the date is MMYYYY only. Here's a data sample:

```
                       DATE
Out[3]    0           081972
          1           051967
          2           101964
          3           041975
          4           071976
```

I tried:

```
df['DATE'].apply(pd.to_datetime(format='%m%Y'))
```

and

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m%Y')
```

I got Runtime Error both times

Then

```
df['DATE'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

it worked for the other not shown columns(with DDMMYYYY format), but generated future dates with df['DATE'] because it reads the dates as MMDDYY instead of MMYYYY.

```
            DATE
0       1972-08-19
1       2067-05-19
2       2064-10-19
3       1975-04-19
4       1976-07-19
```

Expect output:

```
          DATE
0       1972-08
1       1967-05
2       1964-10
3       1975-04
4       1976-07
```

If this question is a duplicate please direct me to the original one, I wasn't able to find any suitable answer.

Thank you all in advance for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First if error is raised obviously some datetimes not match, you can test it by `errors='coerce'` parameter and [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), because for not matched values are returned missing values:

```
print (df)
     DATE
0   81972
1   51967
2  101964
3   41975
4  171976 <-changed data


print (pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m%Y', errors='coerce'))
0   1972-08-01
1   1967-05-01
2   1964-10-01
3   1975-04-01
4          NaT
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m%Y', errors='coerce').isna()])
     DATE
4  171976
```

Solution with output from changed data with converting to datetimes and the to months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m%Y', errors='coerce').dt.to_period('m')
print (df)
      DATE
0  1972-08
1  1967-05
2  1964-10
3  1975-04
4      NaT
```

Solution with original data:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m%Y', errors='coerce').dt.to_period('m')
print (df)

0  1972-08
1  1967-05
2  1964-10
3  1975-04
4  1976-07
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done:

```
df['date_formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(
    dict(
        year=df['DATE'].str[2:], 
        month=df['DATE'].str[:2], 
        day=1
    )
)
```

Maybe this helps. Works for your sample data.